# What to memoize in Dynamic programming questions?

Tags: dynamic-programming

How do you know what to memoize in top-down Dynamic Programming problems?

I understand it is to do with capturing the permutations of state. E.g. in the Fibonacci numbers question, it’s memoizing the Fibonacci sequence `fib(8) = 21`. I understand that; it’s a pure function and input results to output.

However, with more difficult Dynamic Programming problems, what to memoize isn’t that obvious, because it seems to me that it usually requires the previous state.

For example, for 474. Ones and Zeros:

https://leetcode.com/problems/ones-and-zeroes/description/

You should memoize the `m` and `n` and `current index`.

But surely at any given index and m and n, it would be different depending on the previous values (it gets all added together)? Say you are on index 300, with m being 50 and n being 20, the memoized answer will really depend on the previous value

To me it’s like saying I want to get to Starbucks, but oh, you are facing left, so you should turn right and go forward. This is not true, as you’d need to know your accumulated current position

Please advise.

Comment: wonder if you read what [tag:interview] tag says, "DO NOT ASK ANY QUESTIONS WHERE YOU FEEL THIS TAG APPLIES!"

Comment: @gnat where do I ask then?

Comment: see [I have a question, but it may not fit best on Software Engineering. Where else can I ask it?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8066/31260)

Comment: @gnat Could you maybe explain to Dolan in what way this question is off-topic for this site? As far as I know, algorithm questions are allowed. If your only argument is the [interview] tag, I am pretty sure we can safely remove it as this question is not exactly related to interviews.

Comment: Thanks Vincent. I have removed the interview tag @gnat. Happy?

Answer (score 2):

Memoization is an *optimization*, not a solution.

> what to memoize isn’t that obvious

Write the solution first, and then memoize whatever you redundantly compute more than once. Trying to skip the naive recursion and go straight to the memoized version is probably a false economy.

---

For your linked problem, write a naive recursive solution first, (without `@lru_cache` or whatever) and just *see* what argument->result pairs recur, and could have been memoized. Print them out and watch it go. Then apply optimizations *after* you understand what is being computed and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

For the ones and zeros problem, the original problem has one answer. There is a one size of the largest subset of `strs` using at most `m` 0's and `n` 1's.

The memoized results are for the same problem, only with smaller values for each parameter. It's like asking what if we had fewer 0's, or fewer 1's to use.

Smaller values of `strs` here would be if we could couldn't use the last element, or last two elements and so on. So the memoized value of `(currentIndex, m, n)` would be the size of the largest subset of `strs` using any elements from index 0 to `currentIndex`, and at most `m` 0's and `n` 1's. This includes the previous values by being the largest possible subset using any of the previous values.